# json list manipulation in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, sorting

Quick question on Json list manipulation.

I have json data that has following format

```
[
 "fruits", 
 "apple", 
 "{\n    \"color\": \"red\",\n    \"harvest\": \"ready\"\n}\n",
 "{\n    \"color\": \"green\",\n    \"harvest\": \"not ready\"\n}\n",
 "veggies",
 "spinach" 
 "{\n    \"color\": \"green\",\n    \"harvest\": \"not ready\"\n}\n",
 "{\n    \"color\": \"light green\",\n    \"harvest\": \"not ready\"\n}\n"
]
```

I wanted to bring any string that is before "{" (Example: apple and spinach) into into "Key-Value" and add a static "keys" like "name" and "features" to json, finally it would look something like this:

```
    {
     "fruits":{"name":"apple",
     "features":[
     {
     "color":"red",
     "harvest":"ready"
     }",
     {"color":"green" 
     "harvest":"not ready"
      ]},
     "veggies":{"name":"spinach",
     "features":[
     {
     "color":"green",
     "harvest":"notready"
     },
     {
     "color":"light green",
     "harvest":"not ready"
     ]}
    }
```

Comment: How do you get this JSON?  is this in a json file? or stored in a variable via string?  I ask because you have "\n" carriage returns.

Comment: i get via string

Comment: is each element on it's own line always?

Comment: yes, each element on its own line. thanks for checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions to give you ideas how to proceed:

With the list of strings that you provide (I think there's one comma missing, after `"spinach"`)

```
strings = [
    "fruits",
    "apple",
    "{\n    \"color\": \"red\",\n    \"harvest\": \"ready\"\n}\n",
    "{\n    \"color\": \"green\",\n    \"harvest\": \"not ready\"\n}\n",
    "veggies",
    "spinach",
    "{\n    \"color\": \"green\",\n    \"harvest\": \"not ready\"\n}\n",
    "{\n    \"color\": \"light green\",\n    \"harvest\": \"not ready\"\n}\n"
]
```

this

```
import json

items = []
for string in strings:
    try:
        items.append(json.loads(string))
    except:
        items.append(string)
```

gives you (`print(items)`) the following list:

```
['fruits',
 'apple',
 {'color': 'red', 'harvest': 'ready'},
 {'color': 'green', 'harvest': 'not ready'},
 'veggies',
 'spinach',
 {'color': 'green', 'harvest': 'not ready'},
 {'color': 'light green', 'harvest': 'not ready'}]
```

Now this then

```
results = {}
items = iter(items)
while True:
    try:
        category = next(items)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    
    results[category] = {
        'name': next(items),
        'features': [next(items), next(items)]
    }
```

produces (`print(results)`)

```
{'fruits': {'features': [{'color': 'red', 'harvest': 'ready'},
                         {'color': 'green', 'harvest': 'not ready'}],
            'name': 'apple'},
 'veggies': {'features': [{'color': 'green', 'harvest': 'not ready'},
                          {'color': 'light green', 'harvest': 'not ready'}],
             'name': 'spinach'}}
```

So far, so good, but I suspect that your list of strings is actually longer. Most likely it contains other fruits or veggies that have to be included in the result. To do this you need adjust the structure of the program (including the structure of results) accordingly.